# PyDev and Eclipse - Is there any way to show the functions documentation when hovering it?

Tags: eclipse, pydev

[image: PyDev - hover function]
I want to check the functions documentation when hovering it, similar to what happens when I'm coding in Java, in Eclipse IDE.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It usually does show it... the problem is that in this particular case the type inference engine is not finding the docstring -- i.e.: it seems `random.randint` just as an assign to `Random._randint` and is not following it.

In this particular case you can ask to get completions for `random` by introspecting it with a shell instead of using the static analysis type inference.

You can do that by adding `random` to the `Forced Builtins` as explained in: https://www.pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html#PyDevInterpreterConfiguration-ForcedBuiltins

i.e.: by doing that it shows the following for me (note that when it can, the hover shows not only the docstring but also the source code, which provides the signature as well as the docstring):

[image]

Comment: Hmmm, I see, I wonder why it doesn't automatically add those into Forced Builtins.
Do you know by any change if there's some kind of good "type helper", "AI" similar to what exists in Visual Studio Code with the Python extension, or Kite?

Anyway thank you for your help, it worked.

Comment: The forced builtins setting by default has only what's available as `sys.builtin_module_names` and plus some other hard-coded values where it's known to solve issues (so, I just added `random` there: https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/commit/8a13cc1f621376138dbaeb6fc465947a6394a905) ;)

Comment: As a note, I'm not aware of another thing such as Kite.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same problem today, and was able to fix it on the Window --> Preferences --> PyDev --> Editor --> Hover screen.  On that screen I chose the radio button for *Combine Hovers*, and after applying that change, I got pop-up info when hovering over variables/functions both defined within my script and defined in imported modules.

[image: Eclipse PyDev Hover preference screen]